# How to detect when the Windows print spooler is hung in .NET

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, printing

We have an WPF/WinForm application that uses a 3rd party WPF RTF control (TxTextControl). The RTF control accesses the default printer info in order to configure the page layout when the control is created. When the print spooler service is hung, this initialization hangs the entire application. We have another WinForm RTF control (Tern) that has the same issue if you don't set a flag to disable the print capability.

The print spooler hanging isn't typically a big problem, but our app runs in Citrix which has some issues with this. Here's one of many support articles you can find about the problem:

https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX113789

We have limited control over what printer setup our customers use. I would like to put some code into the app startup to detect the hung spooler and warn the user without hanging the app. The objects in System.Printing and WMI APIs I have tried so far result in app hangs.

(The situation can be simulated by attaching WinDbg to the spooler service and breaking.)

Any ideas of how I could put a timeout on detecting the status and decide that it's hung after that timeout expires? Would it be best to try running this detection process in a separate AppDomain?